# What is a single word for a day full of appointments?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English to represent `a day full of appointments` ?

Comment: A sample sentence might help people with their suggestions.

Comment: I always say that my calendar looks like a losing game of tetris, but that's more than one word.

Comment: Are you trying to translate from another language that happens to have a single word for this? If so can you give us this word? (I don't think there is a single word in English but knowing the original might help discover one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **book** -- transitive verb
>
> Reserve (accommodations, a place, etc.);
>
> **1.3 (be booked up)** Have all appointments or places reserved; be full. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/book)

You could say *We're booked up.* or  *This past weekend I was fully/completely booked.* It's used primarily by people and businesses that offer a service. I think a businessman would say *I had a day full of appointments.* or *I had appointments all day long.* Informal expressions like *a jam-packed day* don't necessarily refer to appointments.